# Property of matrix determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

So, recently my tutor showed through a couple of examples that if you take $2$ matrices say $A_{\;3 \times 2}$ and $B _{\;2 \times 3}$ then we will either have $\det. (AB) =0$ or $\det . (BA)=0$ and then challenged us to prove it. I have tried and even saw a couple of videos on linear algebra but I am nowhere closer to figuring it out. He said that the only thing that needs to be ensured was that both $AB$ and $BA$ exist.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that this is not true if the matrices are square.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** The rank of a matrix product satisfies $$\operatorname{rank} (PQ) \leq \max \{\operatorname{rank} P, \operatorname{rank} Q\} .$$ If $A$ has size $m \times n$, $m \neq n$, and $B$ has size $n \times m$, what are the possible ranks of $A, B$, and what are the sizes of $AB, BA$?

Comment: I'm sorry I thought about it and I thought over it but I am not clear on how to proceed with this, could you possibly elaborate?

Comment: @PrakharNagpal Have you answered the questions in Travis's answer? You can suppose without loss of generality that $n<m$ if that helps. If $A$ is $m \times n$ and $B$ is $n \times m$, what are the dimensions of $AB$ and $BA$? Also, given that the rank of a matrix is the number of linearly independent columns, what can you say about the ranks of $A$ and $B$ (some sort of bound)? Now apply the product inequality in Travis's answer, and use the fact that a square matrix has determinant $0$ if and only if its columns are linearly dependent.